# Error 0xc00d36c4 when open an mp4 downloaded from an html source

Tags: java, mp4

I am trying to download an mp4 file of a web page via java, but when I go to save it on my device and then open it I get the error "0xc00d36c4" or the program says that the file is corrupted.
This happens to me both if I open it with VLC and with any other programs like "Film & TV by Microsoft".
I leave you here the code of my program.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String code = getCode("https://www.animesaturn.it/ep/Naruto-ITA-ep-2");
            URL url = new URL(getMP4Url(code));
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            //Add the Property
            connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity;q=1, *;q=0");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "__cfduid=d42d9ef9cb8f4049d77bf29806929f3591600593349; _ga=GA1.2.1851438234.1600593351; _gid=GA1.2.1325787872.1600593351; 494668b4c0ef4d25bda4e75c27de2817=ea1b335c-3d0b-40f7-bb25-b91ab367d256:1:2");
            connection.addRequestProperty("DNT", "1");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Host", "server9.animesaturn.it");
            connection.addRequestProperty("If-Range", "\"4046154-5ae57e25d5964\"");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=4784128-13303807");//13303807 1599067366709604
            connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.animesaturn.it/watch?file=3ZqYJugfVUOq");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "video");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "no-cors");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-site");
            connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36");
            //Open the stream and save the file
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.mp4"));
            for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1; ) {
                out.write(b);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getMP4Url(String code) throws IOException {
        String contentPage = getContentPage(new URL("https://www.animesaturn.it/watch?file=" + code));
        //System.out.println(contentPage);
        //System.exit(0);
        int index = contentPage.indexOf(".mp4") + 4;
        contentPage = contentPage.substring(0, index);
        index = contentPage.lastIndexOf("\"") + 1;
        return (contentPage.substring(index));
    }

    private static String getCode(String stringUrl) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        String contentPage = getContentPage(url);
        //System.out.println(contentPage);
        int index = contentPage.indexOf("watch?file=");
        contentPage = contentPage.substring(index);
        index = contentPage.indexOf("=") + 1;
        contentPage = contentPage.substring(index);
        index = contentPage.indexOf("\"");
        return (contentPage.substring(0, index));
    }

    private static String getContentPage(URL url) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String ln = reader.readLine();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        while (ln != null) {
            text.append(ln).append("\n");
            ln = reader.readLine();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: `for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1; ) {` that's abusing a `for` statement, if you ask me :)

Comment: As for your problem, have you checked what's actually inside the file? Are you sure that... ehm... fine website is not returning you something that is *not* a video file?

Comment: Why you use Range if your header? you must read all content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two lines and it will work:

```
connection.addRequestProperty("If-Range", "\"4046154-5ae57e25d5964\"");
connection.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=4784128-13303807");//13303807 1599067366709604
```

HTTP [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header makes servers to send only a part of a file, while you would need the entire one. [`If-Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Range) is also something similar.

Without these headers your code will download a correct 20-minute video (64 megabytes).